# Transfer ratings and/or Playlists from Windows Media Player to Amazon Music (or vice versa)

Tags: migrate-data, amazon-music

Is there a way to upload my *playlists* from Windows Media Player to Amazon Music?

(I uploaded the music OK, just can't figure out how to upload the playlists and, ideally, ratings.)